# Loop for apply,sapply function for create table

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

| CHR | Start_pos | End_pos | SNP | plink.A2 | plink.A1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 72837488 | 72837558 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 74993592 | 74993592 | rs1514174 | T | C |
| 1 | 78049140 | 78049140 | rs17381664 | C | T |

Simply my data look like this, but I have 1000 more rows.

I want to add "71 141 211 281 351 421 491 561 631 701" to Start_pos and End_pos for every row and create a new row. Adding rows will have same CHR and SNP numbers and plink.A2 and plink.A1 values.

Final table should look like this

| CHR | Start_pos | End_pos | SNP | plink.A2 | plink.A1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 72837488 | 72837558 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72837559 | 72837628 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72837630 | 72837699 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72837700 | 72837769 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72837770 | 72837839 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72837840 | 72837909 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72837910 | 72837979 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72837980 | 72838049 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72838050 | 72838119 | rs7531118 | C | T |
| 1 | 72838120 | 72838189 | rs7531118 | C | T |

This table is only for first row of first table, i have to do this for other two-rows.

I hope you all understand my problem, English is not my first language.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option where we convert the 'Start_pos', 'End_pos' to a `list` column by adding with a vector of 'v1' after doing the `rowwise`, then `unnest` the `list` columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(Start_pos = list(c(Start_pos, Start_pos + v1)),
         End_pos = list(c(End_pos, End_pos + v1))) %>% 
  unnest(c(Start_pos, End_pos))
```

---

Or another option is `crossing` to create the combinations and then `mutate` the 'pos' columns by adding with the column 'v1'

```
df1 %>%
   crossing(v1 = c(0, v1)) %>%
   mutate(across(ends_with('pos'), ~ . + v1), v1 = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 33 x 6
#     CHR Start_pos  End_pos SNP       plink.A2 plink.A1
#   <int>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   
# 1     1  72837488 72837558 rs7531118 C        T       
# 2     1  72837559 72837629 rs7531118 C        T       
# 3     1  72837629 72837699 rs7531118 C        T       
# 4     1  72837699 72837769 rs7531118 C        T       
# 5     1  72837769 72837839 rs7531118 C        T       
# 6     1  72837839 72837909 rs7531118 C        T       
# 7     1  72837909 72837979 rs7531118 C        T       
# 8     1  72837979 72838049 rs7531118 C        T       
# 9     1  72838049 72838119 rs7531118 C        T       
#10     1  72838119 72838189 rs7531118 C        T       
# … with 23 more rows
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Start_pos = c(72837488L, 
74993592L, 78049140L), End_pos = c(72837558L, 74993592L, 78049140L
), SNP = c("rs7531118", "rs1514174", "rs17381664"), plink.A2 = c("C", 
"T", "C"), plink.A1 = c("T", "C", "T")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

v1 <- c(71, 141, 211, 281, 351, 421, 491, 561, 631, 701)
```